# Not able to remove folder name inspite of delting all files inside it in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am deleting output folders before running my spark job .
Sometime it deletes it but sometime it delete all the files inside it but top level folder still remains .

I have sub folders kind of structure .

This is how i am deleting the folders .

```
def DeleteDescrFolder(fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem, descrFileURL: String) = {
    val bDescr = fs.exists(new Path(descrFileURL))
    if (true.equals(bDescr)) {
      val outputFile = fs.globStatus(new Path(descrFileURL))
      for (DeleteFilePath <- outputFile) {
        fs.delete(DeleteFilePath.getPath)
      }
      println("Descr File is delete from  " + descrFileURL)
    } else {
      println(descrFileURL + "Decsr Does not Exist")
    }
  }
```

How can i remove folder name also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the files inside the folder specified. Try the following code which will delete the folder as well

```
def DeleteDescrFolder(fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem, descrFileURL: String) = {
  if (fs.exists(new Path(descrFileURL))) {
    try{
      fs.delete(new Path(descrFileURL),true)
      println("Descr folder is deleted " + descrFileURL)
    }catch{case e: Exception =>
      print("exeption "+e)
    }
  } else {
    println(descrFileURL + "Decsr Does not Exist")
  }
}
```